# Get Javascript web console log formatted string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, console

Is there a way to access the formatted string from a console log with formatting specifiers?

https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter

Given the following log message:

```
console.log('message with %s formatting specifiers %i', 'various', '01');
```

I would like the following string made available to be used later in the application:

```
message with various formatting specifiers 1
```

Comment: So use template literals in JavaScript, what is in the console line is not available. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great `String.prototype.printf()` function that i've found off a website for this purpose. It is similar to what you want to achieve. This is the whole prototype that you want to add to your javascript page.

```
String.prototype.printf = function (obj) {
  var useArguments = false;
  var _arguments = arguments;
  var i = -1;
  if (typeof _arguments[0] == "string") {
    useArguments = true;
  }
  if (obj instanceof Array || useArguments) {
    return this.replace(/\%s/g,
    function (a, b) {
      i++;
      if (useArguments) {
        if (typeof _arguments[i] == 'string') {
          return _arguments[i];
        }
        else {
          throw new Error("Arguments element is an invalid type");
        }
      }
      return obj[i];
    });
  }
  else {
    return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
    function (a, b) {
      var r = obj[b];
      return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
    });
  }
};
```

After you've included it, this line of code returns `Hello I am foo bar`

```
console.log("Hello I am " + "%s %s".printf(["foo", "bar"])); //returns foo bar
```

Please see  [here](https://monocleglobe.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/everybody-needs-a-little-printf-in-their-javascript/)  for more info

**If you are using Node.JS**

If you're using Node.js, you can require util node module, and use `util.format()` function. Please see the code down below.

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.format('Hi %s', 'Jack'));
//returns Hi Jack
```

Comment: Thanks - The node.js library will be sufficient for us as a pre-step since it supports the same formatter options as console.

Comment: Thank you too :) @Andrew

Answer (score 1):

I can't find documentation for this, but it appears to be built into console.log now:
`console.log( "native %s", "support" )`